# Resize Link Highlight Area in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, highlighting, navbar

I have made a navbar in the center of my page using Twitter Bootstrap. I have arranged the three icons in the center with a distance between them. When I hover on one of them, the text is not in the center of the highlighted portion. It looks as below. I want Home or Tags to be exactly at the center of highlighted portion.

[image]

Here is my small related piece of code.

```
.navbar .nav > li > a 
{
 float: none ;
 padding: 10px 100px 8px 0px ;
 color: #777777 ;
 text-decoration: none ;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #444 ;
 font-size:20px ;
}


.navbar .nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover 
{
  color: silver ;
  text-decoration: none ;
  background-color:ThreeDFace  #444 ;   
}
```

Comment: have you tried, text-align: center ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you !!

Change this CSS Styling

```
.navbar .nav > li > a 
{
 float: none ;
 padding: 10px 100px 8px 0px ;
 color: #777777 ;
 text-decoration: none ;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #444 ;
 font-size:20px ;
}
```

to this

```
.navbar .nav > li > a 
{
 float: none ;
 width: 100px; 
 text-align: center;
 color: #777777 ;
 text-decoration: none ;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #444 ;
 font-size:20px ;
}
```

and Done :)